# Adding all list items to single class

Tags: html, css

Instead of adding a individual class to each list items, is there a way to add a single class to a whole set of list item at once?

CSS

```
<li class="foot_nav">Home</li>
<li class="foot_nav">Discovery</li>
<li class="foot_nav">Subjects</li>
<li class="foot_nav">Guide</li>
<li class="foot_nav">About us</li>
```

Thanks

Comment: yes, you can use :nt-child

Comment: you got so many answer ..accept one and close the question

Comment: I have no idea what is the question anymore.. "nest large list into single list"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Esko , Any way, my problem is solved, thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply the class to the entire ul and then targeth the ul li using CSS

```css
.foot_nav{list-style:none}

.foot_nav li:nth-child(even) {background:red}

.foot_nav li:nth-child(odd) {background:yellow}
```

```html
<ul class="foot_nav">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Discovery</li>
  <li>Subjects</li>
  <li>Guide</li>
  <li>About us</li>
</ul>
```

```
<ul class="foot_nav">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Discovery</li>
  <li>Subjects</li>
  <li>Guide</li>
  <li>About us</li>
</ul>

//css
.foot_nav li{//styling}
```

Comment: that did not work out well, as a example if you apply background color, it will appear as single bar, not as a individual back ground for each list item.

Comment: @Manoj Wijesooriya - answer updated to show how you can have different backgrounds for the ul li's

Answer (score 2):

It's only one way - JS. Jquery for example:

```
$('li').addClass('foot_nav');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a class to parent and use child selector:

```css
.foot_nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="foot_nav">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Discovery</li>
  <li>Subjects</li>
  <li>Guide</li>
  <li>About us</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you need it for?

Maybe you should add the class to its parent.

```
<ul class="foot_nav">
<li></li>
…
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.foot_nav
{
  list-style-type:none;

}
.foot_nav li
{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="foot_nav">
<li >Home</li>
<li >Discovery</li>
<li >Subjects</li>
<li >Guide</li>
<li >About us</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in **JavaScript** should do the trick:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
    lis[i].className = lis[i].className += " foot_nav"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
 .list-item li{
 }

.list-item:nth-child(1){
}
.list-item:nth-child(2){
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-item">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```